# Getting DOM manipulation out of controller in Angular 1.2.29

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've started work on an e-learning delivery platform and we've chosen Angularjs (1.2.29 because we still have users on IE8). Our team is all relatively new to Angular and we're not sure what is best practise to deliver the system to brief.

The aim is to have a very component-based structure, where designers can simply edit a json file, adding named components as they require them. Behind the scenes, each component should have its own html template, js functionality file and css.

We have a working system which so far includes 'paragraph' and 'image' components. The next step was to add a 'popup' component that has some interactive functionality.

The problem I can already see forming is that we're adding the component functionality into the 'pageController' in our app.js file, which I suspect is a very bad idea, not least because if we keep adding each component's functionality there, the file will become huge and unwieldy. Here's the pageController in app.js, so far:

```
app.controller('pageCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'content', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, content) {

    $http.get('json/page' + $routeParams.pageId + '.json')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.page = data;
    });

$scope.getStyle = function(singleCase, device) {
    if (singleCase == undefined)
        return '';

    return assignBootstrap(singleCase, device);
}

// function for new, interactive 'popup' component
$scope.showPopup = function (showOnClick) {
    // presentation logic located here. This is a bad idea, right?
    if ($('#'+showOnClick).hasClass('overlay')) {
        $('#page_container').append($('#'+showOnClick));
    }
    $( '#' + $( '#' + showOnClick ).attr('data-replaces') ).remove();
    $('.popup').addClass("hidden");
    $('#'+showOnClick).removeClass("hidden");
}

    $scope.pageId = $routeParams.pageId;
}]);
```

I have read and watched a lot of tutorials, and pages on the Angular site, but comprehending how to get the specific requirements of our project working with Angular is proving difficult.

This page...
https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.29/docs/guide/controller
...tells me that DOM manipulation code should be encapsulated in directives (either custom or built in, I assume).

Given that we want to end up with small .js files associated with each required component, should we instead refactor the design to use custom element (restrict: "E") directives to encapsulate the functionality?

The information I've encountered is so concept-based and abstract, it is difficult to know how the concepts should be best applied to a working project.

Is it a good use of 'element restricted' directives (effectively custom html tags) to encapsulate our individual components' code? I can imagine ending up with a list of custom html tags that define the components we need. Is that even what element directives are for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, that's the purpose of directives: inject in your HTML some reusable components in an intelligent way.

Think if you ever need to bind a variable to your "components": you'll be able to do it easily and with no pain at all, by using directives/components.

This way of using your views goes against the angular way of things:

```
$scope.showPopup = function (showOnClick) {
    // presentation logic located here. This is a bad idea, right?
    if ($('#'+showOnClick).hasClass('overlay')) {
        $('#page_container').append($('#'+showOnClick));
    }
    $( '#' + $( '#' + showOnClick ).attr('data-replaces') ).remove();
    $('.popup').addClass("hidden");
    $('#'+showOnClick).removeClass("hidden");
}
```

because you'll end up replicate this code all over your controllers.

.

Alternatively, if you don't need any form of logic inside your "containers", you could use ng-include with templates to inject html in your pages, like this:

```
<div ng-include"myContainer.html"></div>
```

and somewhere in your html pages, include a script

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myContainer.html">
  <!-- content -->
</script>
```